# UITableViewCell messing up layout on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created custom cells for my tableview, I'm updating them on cellForRowAtIndexPath and it all works well.... but as soon as I touch a cell, the layout messes up, I think it all goes to align at the very left of the cell I touched. Like in the 2nd picture.

Any idea of what could be happening?

[image: This is when the table view is first created]
[image: This is after touching the cells]

Here is the code of the ViewController and of the Cell:

StoriesViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ReactViewController.h"
#import "StoriesCell.h"
#import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"

@interface StoriesViewController : ReactViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *downloadedObject;

@end
```

StoriesViewController.m

```
#import "StoriesViewController.h"

@interface StoriesViewController ()

@end

@implementation StoriesViewController

NSArray *stories;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    stories = [self.downloadedObject objectForKey:@"stories"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [stories count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"StoryPreview";

    StoriesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[StoriesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = [currentObject objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.txtLabel.text = [currentObject objectForKey:@"text"];
    [cell.avatarImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[currentObject objectForKey:@"avatar"]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                            options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

StoriesCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StoriesCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *authorLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *txtLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatarImageView;

@end
```

StoriesCell.m

```
#import "StoriesCell.h"

@implementation StoriesCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{ }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

The layout is setup on Storyboard like in the following picture: [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5mCl.png)

Comment: What is that ReactViewController you are inheriting from? Perhaps its didSelectRowAtIndexPath is doing something. Also, do you use AutoLayout? It seems like a typical constraint problem.

Comment: good point :) but unfortunately I checked, and no... it's just a UITableViewController with a couple of functions that are used by views to handle some common layout setup...but nothing that would have an effect on the rows.

Comment: What about Auto Layout then? Do you have any constraints set in the storyboard? Because according to your code, everything should be alright

Comment: uh, wow I had no idea what Auto Layout was... I googled it now and checked: it was enabled. Now I disabled it and doesn't change on selection anymore: everything is wrongly aligned left like in the 2nd picture -.-'' I guess I just need to setup things well on the code at this point.
thanks a lot tho!! if you post it as a reply I can approve it ;)

Comment: no ok now I can't move the elements out of the left border -.- I'm using things like: cell.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 20, 200, 50) but doesn't seem to work. Any idea why? I'll try a bit more.